# _mapper.Map<IDataReader, IEnumerable<T>>(dt.CreateDataReader()); gives error Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-2.2

I am creating an automap from Datatable to My Class. the data column matches to class field names. Data table contains more columns than class.

I have created a profile and added it to IServiceCollection but still its not working.

```
public class DestClass
{
   public string id_branch { get; set; }
   public string city{ get; set; }
   public string User{ get; set; }
}

public DestMappingProfile()
{
   CreateMap<IDataReader, DestClass>();
}
```

In Startup ConfigureServices

```
var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
 {
    mc.AddProfile(new DestMappingProfile());
 });

 IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
 services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

At repository level

```
 var mapper = _mapper.Map<IDataReader, IEnumerable<DestClass>> 
 (dt.CreateDataReader());
```

I want all the collection of returned data into this DestClass.

Comment: What do you mean by "its not working"? Empty data? Exception? Fire?

Comment: the data is the I am getting error at mapping level var mapper = _mapper.Map<IDataReader, IEnumerable<DestClass>> 
 (dt.CreateDataReader());

Comment: You have created a map between DestClass and IDataReader, Not IDataReader and IEnumerable<DestClass>, map it explicitly to an IEnumerable<DestClass>

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Data